# How to select all thumbnails in "Page Thumbnails" pane in Pages via AppleScript

Tags: applescript, pages

I need to click the *Page Thumbnails* pane (which is shown at the left side on the screenshot below) in a Pages document and then select all the pages there, ...

[image]

and there is a problem in the first step. When I click the *Page Thumbnails* manually and record this action with Automator, it looks as follows:

```
click list 1 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of window "test-document" of application process "Pages"
```

But when I try the same line in AppleScript, it doesn't seem to work. Why?

```
activate application "Pages"
tell application "System Events"
    click list 1 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of window "test-document" of application process "Pages"
    keystroke "a" using command down
end tell
```

Edit: Note the document is in Page Layout mode (File > Convert to Page Layout)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as if only 1 Page Thumbnail can be selected at a time. If you go ahead and manually select 1 page thumbnail then try `control + A`, nothing happens.  Also if you go to the "Edit" menu while one page thumbnail is selected, you will see that the option to "Select All" is grayed out.

If you are interested, I believe this is a more stable way to script the showing of Page Thumbnails

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Pages"
        set frontmost to true
        repeat until frontmost
            delay 0.1
        end repeat
        click menu item "Page Thumbnails" of menu ¬
            "View" of menu bar item "View" of menu bar 1
    end tell
end tell
```

---

**Updated Post To Address The Comment From @jsx97**

This should work for you but you may need to adjust the `delay` times

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Pages"
        set frontmost to true
        repeat until frontmost
            delay 0.1
        end repeat
        click menu item "Convert to Page Layout" of menu ¬
            "File" of menu bar item "File" of menu bar 1
        delay 1
        click button "Convert" of sheet 1 of window 1
        delay 0.1
        click menu item "Page Thumbnails" of menu ¬
            "View" of menu bar item "View" of menu bar 1
        delay 0.1
        set focused of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of window 1 to true
        delay 1
        select last list of list 1 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of window 1
            delay 1
        keystroke "a" using {command down}
    end tell
end tell
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that the document is in page layout mode (File > Convert to Page Layout). For such documents there is no problem to manually select thumbnails with Command-A or with menu item Edit > Select All. But I need to automate it. And the first step for this is to "click" this sidebar somehow.

Comment: @jsx97 I think the edit to my post is what you may be looking for.

Comment: Oh, thank you so much!